# OroCRM and Mailchimp Integration

Tags: mailchimp, orocrm

I have created a new Mailchimp integration in my OroCrm backend and connection is checked (valid API Key). ORO daemon us running. Everything is OK at this point.
In Mailchimp a list is created correctly.
When I create a new Marketing list in Oro (contact entity and dynamic ) and try to connect it to Mailchimp, MailChimp Subscribers List is empty.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Find your integration there System/ Integrations/ Manage Integrations, click on it and 'Schedule Sync', after that check your 'MailChimp Subscribers List'. Please note that cron daemon must be run.